# Is there a build-in function to create a matrix m such that m(r,c) = fun(r,c)

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to make the following code vectorized:(where `fun` is a custom function)

```
m = zeros(R,C);
for r = 1:R
    for c = 1:C
        m(r,c) = fun(r,c);
    end
end
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to make it clear, **there is no generic "vectorized" solution** if `fun` does not accept vectors (or matrices) for input.

That said, I'll add to nate's answer and say that in case `fun` does not accept matrices you can go about this with:

```
[Y, X] = meshgrid(1:R, 1:C);
m = arrayfun(@(r, c)fun(r, c), X, Y)
```

However you should note that this is not a vectorized solution as `arrayfun` has a `for`-loop under the hood, so while it may be prettier it is probably slower.

Comment: +1, but note that it is not just prettier. Matlab can parallelize the calls to fun, because the computations are independent.

Comment: From my experience it usually isn't so, but you may be right.

Comment: @Andrey: If only `arrayfun` would do that....testing this example shows that `meshgrid` nicely spreads over all my cores, while `arrayfun` sticks to one. `cellfun` and `structfun` too do not use multi-threading, while especially these functions seem excellent candidates for that IMHO (tested with R2010b).

Comment: Thanks,EitanT, that's just what I need!. But I think you have made a mistake here: `[Y X] = meshgrid(1:C,1:R)` or `[X Y] = ndgrid(1:R,1:C)` instead of `[X, Y] = meshgrid(1:R, 1:C)`.

Comment: @Eastsun, yes, it's `[Y, X]` indeed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

use meshgrid:

```
 N = 100 % grid points
 rangex=linspace(-2,2,N);
 rangey=linspace(-2,2,N);
 [x,y] = meshgrid(rangex,rangey);

 %G=fun(x,y);
 G= exp(-(x.^2+y.^2));
 imagesc(G)
```

Comment: +1: This solution works if `fun` can accept matrices as input, but what if not?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but when you have any f(x,y)=... it means it is bound to be a matrix since (x,y) are the x-y coordinates of that matrix...

Comment: You and I are talking about different things. By definition `fun(x, y)` maps a value to each (x, y) pair according to some function or matrix. In other words, in the calculation of `fun` for _a single pair_ (2, 3), you would feed `fun` with a scalar `x = 2` and a scalar `y = 3`, like so: `fun(2, 3)`. Now what if you want to calculate `fun` for several pairs? Can the implementation of `fun` use vectors for `x` and `y`, for example `fun([2 10], [3 27])`? I think `fun` is not guaranteed to deal with such input.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways to do this:

```
G = @(x,y) exp(-(x.*x+y.*y));

% using meshgrid 
% PROS: short, very fast, works only on functions that accept vector/matrix input
% CONST: very large memory footprint
[x,y] = meshgrid(-10:0.1:10);   
m = G(x,y);


% using arrayfun
% PROS: shorter notation than loop, works on functions taking only scalars
% CONS: can be prohibitively slow, especially when nested like this
m = cell2mat(...
    arrayfun(@(x)...
    arrayfun(@(y) G(x,y), -10:0.1:10),...
    -10:0.1:10, 'uniformoutput', false));

% using for-loop
% PROS: intuitive to most programmers, works on functions taking scalars only
% CONS: Boilerplate can grow large, can be slow when the function G(x,y)
%       is not "inlined" due to limitations in JIT
for ii = 1:R
    for jj = 1:C

        m(ii,jj) = exp(-(ii*ii+jj*jj)); % inlined

        m(ii,jj) = G(ii,jj); % NOT inlined (slower)

    end
end
```

Note that the `meshgrid` is way faster than `arrayfun` and the loop, but has the potential to fill up your memory so much that it is impossible to use this method for higher resolutions in the `x` or `y` ranges (without resorting to some sort of block-processing scheme).

I will state here that `arrayfun` is generally a thing to be avoided, since it is often far slower than the loop-counterpart, partly due to JIT acceleration of the loop, and partly because of the overhead involved with anonymous functions (nested triply, in this case).

So, for the `dblquad` example you mentioned in a comment: just using a loop is easiest and fastest.

Comment: I have to disagree with the comparison above, because in your case `G(x, y)` accepts vectors, and I believe that in the OP's example `fun` accepts only scalars.

Comment: Oh, I don't know why my brain skipped over the comments in your code. I apologize for the wrong criticism.

Answer (score 0):

Several Matlab functions can work with matrices as inputs and they give you matrices as outputs. But if fun is custom is easier even! you can actually make `fun` to accept matrices as inputs (it depends in what you are doing of course, sometimes you just can't, but most of times you can) and it will work. Most of the times the difference of accepting matrices or just numbers resides in substituting `*` by `.*` (and the same with other operators). Try:

```
m=[]; %not necesary in this case
r=1:R;
c=1:C;
m=fun(r,c);
```

Comment: But if the custom function can't accept matrices as inputs? Such as: fun = @(a,b) dblquad(@(x,y) x.*y,0,a,0,b)

Comment: Actually don't know. I would make it as you are doing it right now. Check @nate's answer, it may work!